# LibGDX Game is stuttering all of a sudden?

Tags: java, performance, libgdx

I was starting over with a new LibGDX project recently. I'm very used to working with it. But with this project (and every new project I'm setting up recently) stutters a lot. Though the FPS is fine, the movement of the objects is stuttering. I tried switching vsync on and off but it did not help much. How is it possible that all of a sudden this happens? Am I missing something?

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.title = "MyGame";
        config.width = 1280;
        config.height = 800;

        new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(), config);
    }
}

public class MyGame extends Game {

    public void create() {
        this.setScreen(new MainScreen());
    }

    public void dispose() {

    }
}

public class MainScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

    private BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
    private SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();

    private OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    private FitViewport viewport = new FitViewport(1280, 800, camera);

    private Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("some sprite")));

    public void show() {
        batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) {
            sprite.setX(sprite.getX() + 150 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) {
            sprite.setX(sprite.getX() - 150 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        }

        viewport.apply();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection);
        batch.begin();
            font.draw(batch, "Hello LibGDX!", 100f, 100f);
            sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }

    public void dispose() {
        font.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

This is the most basic project I set up to confirm the stutter is there 100% of the time. Currently I'm using the newest version 1.9.10 of LibGDX. And my hardware didn't change since I did my last project btw.

Comment: You're manipulating the position of your sprite directly. Have you tried using a velocity variable, which gets manipuating instead? This can lead to an overall smoother movement.

Comment: I don't see how this would affect the rendering. I mean I have a constant speed update, shouldn't that be fine? If I introduced a velocity var, when it maxes out it will be equal to the fixed update.

Comment: Do you play some sounds also?

Comment: Look at the code up there. There is nothing going on than just rendering a single sprite plus a text.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? It seems to stutter even if everything is switched off...nothing seems to cause it other than the engine itself.

Comment: Same problem here. What is the fix?

Answer (score 0):

```
float getDeltaTime()
```

This value is "smoothed" or averaged over a number of frames so it does not correctly show the -actual- elapsed time since the last frame and so the x increment doesn't truly match the frame delta.

```
float getRawDeltaTime()
```

This does show the delta specifically for the last frame and would eliminate the stuttering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to use the raw delta time and see if it fixes my issue. But what is the purpose of the smoothed delta time then?

Comment: Good question, why indeed? A fix for bugginess essentially. This smoothing only occurs for Android devices, which is the initial target for libGDX, to correct issues caused by early Android devices with intermittent huge rendering issues running up against capped delta time rendering assumptions elsewhere. See this for more details https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/6228 .